# Dudas en el background size y background position

Tags: css

Hola buenas noches soy nuevo en esto de la programación y recién empezando y tengo algunas dudas en fondos css . mi pregunta es cuando se pone en el background size : 100% y en el background position: left bottom¿ Porque no se nota ningún cambio en el fondo de derecha o izquierda pero si de arriba y abajo ?   ¿porque solo cambia el fondo solo de arriba y abajo pero de derecha a izquierda no se mueve la imagen ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRcJ4.jpg)

Comment: Si es `background-size: 100%`, es porque está ocupando el ancho completo y, ¿Donde se movería a los lados? Pues si la imágen no se define su altura, entonces abría? lugar para moverse verticalmente...

Comment: Gracias por responder y disculpa las molestias